# custom php template not working on wordpress when submit form data to next page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

**this is from i have using in custom template**

```
 <form class="register" id="hh" method="POST" action="http://www.website.com/online-registration">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="register-input" placeholder="Name"/> 
      <input type="email"  id="email" name="email" class="register-input" placeholder="Email address" required>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="register-input" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" placeholder="mobile" class="register-input" required />
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" placeholder="Current City" class="register-input" />
      <input type="text" id="qualification" name="qualification" value="" placeholder="Qualification Details" class="register-input" />
      <select id="subject" name="subject"  class="register-input"> 
      <option value=""> Please Select Type </option> 
      <option> Seeker </option>
      <option> Employer </option>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="Message" class="register-input" id="message" name="message"></textarea> 
      <input type="submit" value="Send" name="reg" id="reg" class="register-button">
      </form>
```

**facing problem when data goes to next page**

```
<?php /* Template Name: applyregistration */ ?>
<?php get_header();   include('conn.php');    ?>
```

> Here i get error -Sorry, No Posts Found

```
<?php
 include 'conn.php';

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')

{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Select Tag ***select*** tag.

```
<form class="register" id="hh" method="post" action="formaction.php">

 <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="register-input" placeholder="Name"/> 

  <input type="email"  id="email" name="email" class="register-input" placeholder="Email address" required>

  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="register-input" placeholder="Password">

  <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" placeholder="mobile" class="register-input" required />

<input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" placeholder="Current City" class="register-input" />

 <input type="text" id="qualification" name="qualification" value="" placeholder="Qualification Details" class="register-input" />

  <select id="subject" name="subject"  class="register-input"> 
      <option value=""> Please Select Type </option> 
      <option> Seeker </option>
      <option> Employer </option>
  </select>

   <textarea cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="Message" class="register-input" id="message" name="message"></textarea> 

 <input type="submit" value="Send" name="reg" id="reg" class="register-button">
```

Comment: does not working..still showing message on next page "Sorry, No Posts Found"

Comment: create another page . like formaction.php. see my code.

Comment: and method name change into uppercase to lowercase.

Comment: on php page code is working condition..but when i use this php file as a wordpress template it showing an error...otherwise it was ok on simple php page

Answer (score 0):

**It is the issue of name of variables that i have using in form.. just change the attributes names.. Example - name to name1, email to email1..etc etc..**

Problem Solved

Answer (score 0):

this link is very useful to create customized form in WordPress https://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/